# can I create a pointer to a templated function inside a scope?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I want to create a pointer to a templated function:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T x){}

int main()
{


template <class T>
void (*ptr)(T);


    return 0;
}
```

I got error above: `error C2951: template declarations are only permitted at global or namespace scope`

so I can fix it by declaring the pointer to templated function in a global scope and it works fine:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T x){ cout << "foo()" << endl;}

template <class T>
void (*ptr)(T);


int main()
{

    ptr = foo;
    (*ptr)(7);

    return 0;
}
```

- is there a way to declare a pointer to templated function inside a scope like in the first code?

Comment: Your second code snippet did not *fix* it.

Comment: Templated functions don't even exist until they're instantiated with some type, so a pointer to a function template is impossible. You can get pointers to specific instances, though, like `foo<int>`

Comment: `template <class T> void (*ptr)(T);` would be a variable template since C++14. but usage would be something like `ptr<int> = foo;`.

Comment: [cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/p5UX5G) your second code. And I dont understand how this is supposed to work. There is no way for the compiler to deduce `T` when you do `ptr = foo`.

Comment: what would `int main() { template<class T> /*anything here*/ }` even mean? That's what error C2951 is telling you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A *function-template* is **not** a *function*. And *function-pointers* can only be assigned to functions of matching signatures.

In this declaration:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T x){ cout << "foo()" << endl;}
```

`foo` is a *function-template*. Until it is instantiated before a function is produced. Hence, you can only get a function pointer to an instantiation of `foo`.

---

Say you have a function pointer say `Ktr`, you can only assign it to an instantiation of `foo` as below:

```
void (*Ktr)(int);
Ktr = foo<int>;
```

---

In this declaration:

```
template <class T>
void (*ptr)(T);
```

You declared a [variable template (C++14)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) of a function pointer type taking an object of type `T` as the only argument.

Comment: You can however *inside another template* instantiate the foo template and take a pointer to it. E.g. `template<class U> class usesFooPtr{ void (*ptr)(U) = &foo<U> }`